# how to open the content of a folder in to different rich text boxes?

Tags: c#, file, dialog, richtextbox

I'm trying to open a file dialog and open the files inside a folder into different rich text boxes? but i'm not sure what else I would need to add? could you please help out a new blood.

```
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            tabPage1.Text = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;
        }
```

Comment: what's the problem with the current code?

Comment: instead of opening just one file. im trying to get it to open a folder with multiple files inside and load them into rich text boxes but im stuck.

Comment: Do you want to create the richtextboxes dynamically together with a new tabpage and load them with the content of each file selected?

Comment: `OpenFileDialog` is to open but one file by default. Try to change its `MultiSelect` property to `true`

Comment: I already have the tab pages and rich text boxes it's just getting them to load different files from selecting a folder In the open dialog

Comment: Well, then how many richtextboxes do you have? You can't open more files than the controls available. Are the richtextboxes located in separate tab pages?

Comment: I have 5 files in a folder with 5 rich text boxes on different tab pages

Comment: So you don't really need to select a file but a folder, then display all the 5 files present right?

Comment: That is correct Steve into the 5 different rich text boxes

Comment: @Waypast and what are your richtextboxes instance names? You could populate by `Form.Controls` dynamically. But if you have individual instance, you could also just put the filenames[0] to [4] in my example to individual richtextbox

Comment: They are the default richtextbox1 richtextbox2 and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to allow your user to select a folder and then open the first 5 files present in that folder each one in a different richtextbox then you don't need the `OpenFileDialog`, but the [FolderBrowserDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
// First prepare two list with the richtextboxes and the tabpages
List<RichTextBox> myBoxes = new List<RichTextBox>()
{ richTextBox1, richTextBox2, richTextBox3, richTextBox4, richTextBox5 };
List<TabPage> myPages = new List<TabPage>()
{ tabPage1, tabPage2, tabPage3, tabPage4, tabPage5};


// Now open the folderbrowser dialog 
// (see link above for some of its properties)
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
if(fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath))
    {        
        myBoxes[i].Text = File.ReadAllText(file);
        myPages[i].Text = Path.GetFileName(file);
        i++;

        // Added a warning if the folder contains more than 5 files
        if(i >= 5)
        { 
           MessageBox.Show("Too many files in folder, only 5 loaded");
           break;
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: just added this to my project but im now getting a error under the FolderBrowerDialog fbd = new FolderBroserDialog();

Comment: steve i just tried the code you provided and im still getting the error under.folderBrowserDialog1 fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();

Comment: I see, my typo fixed the spelling for FolderBrowserDialog (not FolderBrowserDialog1), reload the page

Comment: one more quick question how would i make it so that when  the files load the tab page name is the savename of the file not the location?#

Comment: _myPages[i].Text  = Path.GetFileName(file);_

Comment: sorry to ask again but code you please update the code with this?

Answer (score 1):

`OpenFileDialog` is to open but one file by default. Try to change its `MultiSelect` property to `true`. Something like this will do:

```
openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
    for (int i = 0; i < openFileDialog1.FileNames.Length; ++i) {
        RichTextBox rtb = Controls.Cast<Control>().Single(x => x.Name == "richTextBox" + (i + 1).ToString()) as RichTextBox;
        rtb.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileNames[i]);
    }
    tabPage1.Text = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName; //again, I wonder what you want to do with this. If needed be, consider to update this dynamically too
}
```

**Old answer:**

```
openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true; //important: set this to true
richTextBox1.Text = ""; //and you may want to reset this every time
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
    foreach(var filename in openFileDialog1.FileNames) //get file names here
        richTextBox1.Text += File.ReadAllText(filename); //you may want to add enter per file
    tabPage1.Text = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName; //but I wonder what you want to do with this....?
}
```